# Creating a Unified Scrollable Screen with two nested scrollable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm currently working on a screen layout that consists of a row of 5 featured photos at the top, followed by a StaggeredGrid that displays a list of photos with paging. My goal is to implement a unified scrolling behavior that scrolls the entire screen, including both the featured photos section and the StaggeredGrid section.

To achieve this layout, I initially attempted to place the featured photos widget and the StaggeredGrid widget inside a Column. However, this approach resulted in conflicting scrolling behaviors between the Column and the StaggeredGrid, making it impossible to achieve the desired layout.

I'm seeking advice on the best approach to implement this screen layout while maintaining a single unified scrolling behavior for the entire screen. How can I structure my layout to achieve the desired scrolling behavior without conflicts?

[image: Screen_Layout]

Comment: Sounds like you just want to disable the scrolling of the `StaggeredGrid`, and put a scrollable column around the whole thing

Comment: @Jorn Yes exactly, but someone told me that I can do that whole screen just with only a Grid but I don't know how to do such thing because its a StaggeredGrid and I have to identify the columns of the Grid as I create and I tried to place the "Featured" widget above the list by "item" and "items" methods but unfortunately didn't work and provided me something different from what I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was to use the Grid for both the header and the list in this way.

```
LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
        state = listState,
        columns = if (LocalConfiguration.current.orientation == ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 175.dp)
        } else StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2)
    ) {

        item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine, content = {
            featured?.let { Featured(it) }
        })

        item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(15.dp))
        }

        item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine) {
            Text(
                text = "All",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
                color = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.9f)
            )
        }

        item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(5.dp))
        }


        items(pictures.itemCount,
            key = pictures.itemKey { it.id },
            contentType = pictures.itemContentType{ it }) { index ->
            pictures[index]?.let{
                PictureItem(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    item = it,
                    onItemClicked = onPictureItemClicked,
                    height = (it.height / 12)
                )
            }
        }
}
```

This way we have one scroll for the whole page.